# Tomcat 7.50+JDK 64bit 1.7.0.51 start up issues

Tags: java, tomcat

When I launch my Tomcat server via myeclipse. It shows bellowing error.Any one know this issue? Many thanks.

environment:Tomcat 7.50+JDK 64bit 1.7.0.51 start up issues.

```
 Jan 15, 2014 8:46:16 P.M org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
    INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;C:\server\tomcat 7\bin
    Jan 15, 2014 8:46:16 P.M org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Jan 15, 2014 8:46:16 P.M org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Jan 15, 2014 8:46:16 P.M org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO: Initialization processed in 697 ms
    Jan 15, 2014 8:46:16 P.M org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFO: Starting service Catalina
    Jan 15, 2014 8:46:16 P.M org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.50
    Jan 15, 2014 8:46:16 P.M org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\server\tomcat 7\webapps\docs
    Jan 15, 2014 8:46:16 P.M org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory C:\server\tomcat 7\webapps\docs
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.createWebXmlDigester(ContextConfig.java:522)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:843)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:389)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:634)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1230)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1876)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.idFor(DigesterFactory.java:107)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.<clinit>(DigesterFactory.java:59)
        ... 18 more
    Jan 15, 2014 8:46:16 P.M org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\server\tomcat 7\webapps\examples
    Jan 15, 2014 8:46:16 P.M org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory C:\server\tomcat 7\webapps\examples
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.createWebXmlDigester(ContextConfig.java:522)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:843)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:389)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:634)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1230)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1876)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    Jan 15, 2014 8:46:16 P.M org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\server\tomcat 7\webapps\host-manager
    Jan 15, 2014 8:46:16 P.M org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory C:\server\tomcat 7\webapps\host-manager
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.createWebXmlDigester(ContextConfig.java:522)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:843)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:389)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:634)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1230)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1876)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    Jan 15, 2014 8:46:16 P.M org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\server\tomcat 7\webapps\manager
    Jan 15, 2014 8:46:16 P.M org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory C:\server\tomcat 7\webapps\manager
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.createWebXmlDigester(ContextConfig.java:522)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:843)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:389)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:634)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1230)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1876)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    Jan 15, 2014 8:46:16 P.M org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\server\tomcat 7\webapps\ROOT
    Jan 15, 2014 8:46:16 P.M org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory C:\server\tomcat 7\webapps\ROOT
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.createWebXmlDigester(ContextConfig.java:522)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:843)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:389)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:634)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1230)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1876)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    Jan 15, 2014 8:46:16 P.M org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Jan 15, 2014 8:46:16 P.M org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Jan 15, 2014 8:46:16 P.M org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 136 ms
```

Any one know this issue? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a system property to the launch configuration of the tomcat in eclipse.

```
 -Djava.library.path=C:\server\tomcat 7\bin
```

Download the [tcnative.dll](http://tomcat.apache.org/native-doc/) and put it in the bin folder.